# How do you write byte[] array using log4.net

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I have a byte[] with some data in it, I would like to write this byte array AS-IS to the log file using log4.net. The problems that i am facing is that

There are no overload for byte[] in **TextWriter**, so even implementing an **IObjectRenderer** is of no use.
I dont have access to the underlying Stream object of Log4.net
Also tried converting byte[] into char[] still when i write it, it adds an extra byte.

Is this even possible with Log4.net.

Thanx in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

Log files are usually plain text files. It's probably best to log your byte array represented as string.

Have a look at [BitConverter.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a733s97.aspx) or [Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx).

Comment: the only problem with this approach is that the log file would be double the size and also not very readable as the data contains a mix of human readable string and binary info.

Comment: Then don't write it to the log file :-) Log files are for diagnostic messages, not piles of binary data.

Answer (score 3):

Nope.  Have you thought about writing it out as a hex string (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa-in-c))?

Comment: the only problem with this approach is that the log file would be double the size and also not very readable as the data contains a mix of human readable string and binary info.

Comment: If you know how to write out HEX string, you can feel free to write out other string patterns if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I also think that logging any larger data is kind of useless, however, i guess this is what you are looking for - this converts your bytes to string.

```
 System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteArray)
```

I believe you can figure out how to use that for logging.

Pz, the TaskConnect developer

Answer (score 0):

If you are logging into DB then use Binary type with maximum size